# How to move cursor in Xcode smoothly?

Tags: ios, xcode

For example like below gif

[image]

First he is type QL1("") and his cursor's position is locate after double quotes

Then how to move cursor's position between double quotes?

I know i can use arrow key,but i don't want to move my hand on keyboard

So is there have convenient way to move cursor?

Just like we can press Tab to move cursor to different parameter

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: please explain what you want to implement

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything. Xcode is already automatically putting that.

1. Just put a single double quote(")
2. Write whatever you want to write
3. Press the next arrow key (->) and the second single double quote(") will be automatically added.

Hope this helps!